# Oracle Hierarchical Question (Find step siblings)

Tags: oracle, search, tree, hierarchical

I'm working through a problem where, starting at any 'leaf' or child, I can find that child's siblings and step siblings.  To paint a better example, if parent A has two children, and shares one child with parent B, and parent B has two children, one shared with parent A and one shared with parent C, and parent c has two other children not shared with parent B, how do I report all the children? I've tried using recursive with and hierarchical query, but can't seem to get it right.  Below is the table structure and values and my attempts thus far.

```
create table bw_parents(
parent_id char(1) primary key);


create table bw_children(
child_id number(2),
parent_id char(1),
constraint parent_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) references bw_parents
);

insert into bw_parents values('A');

insert into bw_parents values('B');

insert into bw_parents values('C');

insert into bw_parents values('D');

insert into bw_parents values('E');

insert into bw_children values(1,'A');

insert into bw_children values(2,'A');

insert into bw_children values(2,'B');

insert into bw_children values(3,'B');

insert into bw_children values(3,'C');

insert into bw_children values(4,'C');

insert into bw_children values(5,'C');

insert into bw_children values(6,'D');

insert into bw_children values(7,'D');

insert into bw_children values(8,'E');

--hierarchical attempt
select A.parent_id, B.child_id, level
from bw_parents A
join bw_children B ON A.parent_id = B.parent_id
start with A.parent_id = 'B'
connect by nocycle prior B.parent_id = B.parent_id

--recursive with
with r as(
select parent_id, null as child_id
from bw_parents
union all 
select A.parent_id parent_id, B.child_id child_id
from bw_parents A
join bw_children B ON A.parent_id = B.parent_id)

select *
from r
where parent_id = 'B';
```

Comment: Even without reading the rest of your post - if a child has two parents (not just one), then your hierarchy is not what's technically known as a **tree**. In a tree, a parent may have many children, or one, or zero (leaf node), but a child can only have one parent, or zero parents (then it's a root of the tree). Expect that whatever you try to do with a non-tree hierarchy will not be easy.

Comment: Also: Given your input data, in addition to your attempts (BRAVO for including them!) it would help if you would show the exact output you desire, calculated by any means (even by hand) - the answer you would like to be able to get with a query.

Comment: Absolutely, and thank you for your reply.  I would like to specifically filter on a parent id (i.e. 'B') or child_id(i.e. 3)(ideally) and have it return all associated children (i.e. 1,2, 3, 4, 5).

Comment: OK - I actually see your data is not even a "hierarchy" - there are just two levels, parents and children. It seems that if you can find the answer for a parent, then finding the answer for a child is easy (because you can find that child's parent, and use the solution for the parent). Am I getting this right?

Comment: I can use the below, but it doesn't return all of the results.   
    select C.child_id
    from bw_children A
    join bw_parents B ON A.PARENT_ID = B.PARENT_ID
    join bw_children C ON B.parent_id = C.parent_id
    where A.child_id = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple (but perhaps not very performant) solution starting from a given parent:

```
select     distinct child_id
from       bw_children
start with parent_id = 'A'
connect by nocycle (mod(level, 2) = 0 and child_id  = prior child_id ) or 
                   (mod(level, 2) = 1 and parent_id = prior parent_id)
;
```

If you must start with a `child_id`, then you must switch 0 and 1 for the values of `mod(level, 2)` in the `connect by` condition; the rest is unchanged.

Comment: This works brilliantly!  Thank you!  One thing though, how does this work?

Comment: It is pretty clever. It switches back and forth - on odd levels it looks up the parent's children, and on even levels it looks up the child's parents. That leaves a lot of duplicate child_ids, but `distinct` removes them, and `nocycle` means it won't look at parents/children it already saw.

Comment: @kfinity - the duplicates aren't caused by going back and forth between children and parents (that is taken care of by `nocycle`). The duplicates are caused by something else: Parent A may have three children in common with parent B; so then Parent B's children will each appear three times at the next level. I don't think that can be avoided easily (with `connect by` or with recursive `with` query) - neither allows de-duplicating at each step.